# Error [MongoError]: failed to connect to server [cluster0.4mocw.gcp.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect

Tags: node.js, mongodb, visual-studio-code, mongodb-atlas

i'm using mongodb atlas for database, and facing this issue in connectivity

it shows, server is running on port 3000

but then shows Error [MongoError]: failed to connect to server [cluster0.4mocw.gcp.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect

please guide me

Comment: welcome. please add your IP address in network page on atlas and check if its working or not.

Comment: i added current ip, but it didn't worked, then, googeled what is my ip and entered but atlas shows, IPv6 addresses are not supported for the network permission list

Comment: use this for ipv4 [link](https://www.whatismyip.com/)